# How to send a SOAP request in javascript, like in SoapUI

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, xml, soap

I am currently working on a NodeJS project where I need to use some soap/xml/wsdl. The problem is that can't figure out how any of these works, so forgive my ignorance. Here is what I need:

I have this WSDL site that I need to get some answers from. I have figured out how to do this in SoapUI, but I have no idea how to do it in Javascript. The request that I am sending in soapUI looks like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:uni="https://uni-login.dk">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <uni:hentDataAftaler>
         <uni:wsBrugerid>?</uni:wsBrugerid>
         <uni:wsPassword>?</uni:wsPassword>
      </uni:hentDataAftaler>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I also have the wsdl-link:
https://wsiautor.uni-login.dk/wsiautor-v4/ws?WSDL

I have also tried to use some npm-packages in nodeJS (SOAP, Strong-SOAP and Easy-SOAP), but I can't make these work either.

I hope you I have some suggestions and tell me if you need any more information to answer my question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `easy-soap-request`,and this article https://medium.com/@caleblemoine/how-to-perform-soap-requests-with-node-js-4a9627070eb6 may help. It is just a thin wrapper of axios.

My code for your question:

```js
const soapRequest = require('easy-soap-request');
const url = 'https://wsiautor.uni-login.dk/wsiautor-v4/ws';
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8',
    'soapAction': 'https://wsiautor.uni-login.dk/hentDataAftaler',
};
// example data
const xml = `
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:uni="https://uni-login.dk">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <uni:hentDataAftaler>
         <uni:wsBrugerid>?</uni:wsBrugerid>
         <uni:wsPassword>?</uni:wsPassword>
      </uni:hentDataAftaler>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
`;


// usage of module
soapRequest(url, headers, xml).then(({response: {body, statusCode}}) => {
    console.log(body);
    console.log(statusCode);
}).catch((errorBody) => {
    console.error(errorBody);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I have been looking for! I will give you your bounty in a day or two, just to make sure that it all works smooth :)

Comment: Hi again. Do know how to do the exact same in php? If yes, maybe you could make another answer explaining this?

Comment: I have asked another question, if you have the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55834580/how-do-i-make-a-soap-request-in-php-just-like-in-soapui

Comment: I'm getting an error like 
`SOAP FAIL: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined`

Comment: it should be 
`soapRequest({url, headers, xml})`

Answer (score 5):

for those who get an error after following @aristoll answer. Try this, its gonna work

**before**

```
soapRequest(url, headers, xml).....
```

**after**

```
soapRequest({url, headers, xml})......
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be useful to someone in the future:
Change this `(url, headers, xml)` to `( {url, headers, xml})`